# Accents does not appear with php

Tags: php, diacritics

i have a form for post comments but when i comment  with words that have accents, accents does not appear. i have this :

```
>    bla &egrave;&egrave;&egrave;&egrave;&egrave;me
```

i have this on header :
`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`

so it's a problem with php but I do not know what to add in the form

```
My form :

        <?php  print_comments();?>
        <h3> Add comments </h3>
        <form action="article1.php" method="post" >
            <span class="input-label">Name</span>
            <input type="text" required name="comment_name"
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="text" required name="comment_email" 
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <textarea class="input-label" name="comment" required rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="<?php echo $article['_id'];?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Save"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything appears correctly except comments

Answer (score 1):

Probably while you are saving your post in the DB, you are encoding the entities which make the Ampersand (&) to be & and therefore nullifies the remaining characters from being part of the entity.

You can fix this by performing html_entity_decode() on your output string before printing it to the page.

e.g

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode($comments); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your php script `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');`